# How do I make my function into an iteration?

Tags: javascript

The function gets its word from the array variables and function above it, im trying to make the password function print 3 passwords one on each new line. I've watched Code Geek JS for beginners video on iterations to achieve this but I tried implementing it into my code but it didnt work and i dont understand how to make it work in the first place. I thought it'd be better to upload the full code as its working in this state so everyone can understand how its supposed to function. Thanks guys

```js
// This function generates and displays to the console. Word1 - Random Number
function word1() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;  
};


//Function to generate and display to console Word 2 - Random Emotion
var word2 = (function () {
    var verbArray = [];
    verbArray.push("Happy");
    verbArray.push("Sad");
    verbArray.push("Angry");  
    verbArray.push("Cheerful");
    verbArray.push("Ecastatic");
    verbArray.push("Depressed");
    return function() {
      var randomNumber, randomWord;
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * verbArray.length);
      randomWord = verbArray[randomNumber];
      return randomWord;
  
    }; 
  })();
 

// Function to generate and display to console Word 3 - Random Plural Noun

  var word3 = (function () {
    var nounArray = [];
    nounArray.push("House");
    nounArray.push("Cat");
    nounArray.push("Dog");  
    nounArray.push("Phone");
    nounArray.push("Computer");
    nounArray.push("Bottle");
    return function() {
      var randomWord, randomNumber;
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * nounArray.length);
      randomWord = nounArray[randomNumber];
      return randomWord;
    }; 
})();


// Function to generate and display to console Word 4 - Random Verb
var word4 = (function () {
    var verbArray = [];
    verbArray.push("Running");
    verbArray.push("Jumping");
    verbArray.push("Walking");  
    verbArray.push("Sleeping");
    verbArray.push("Jogging");
    verbArray.push("Typing");
    return function() {
      var randomNumber, randomWord;
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * verbArray.length);
      randomWord = verbArray[randomNumber];
      return randomWord;
    }; 
  })();

    

//Function to create password as one-line string
  function passwordfinal() {
    passwordfinal = (word1 ()+ " " + word2 ( ) + " " + word3 ( ) + " " + word4 ( ) + " ");
    return passwordfinal

};

console.log(passwordfinal());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop.

```
function passwordfinal() {
    let passwordfinal = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      passwordfinal += word1 ()+ " " + word2 ( ) + " " + word3 ( ) + " " + word4 ( ) + " ";
    }
    return passwordfinal
};
```

```js
// This function generates and displays to the console. Word1 - Random Number
function word1() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
};


//Function to generate and display to console Word 2 - Random Emotion
var word2 = (function() {
  var verbArray = [];
  verbArray.push("Happy");
  verbArray.push("Sad");
  verbArray.push("Angry");
  verbArray.push("Cheerful");
  verbArray.push("Ecastatic");
  verbArray.push("Depressed");
  return function() {
    var randomNumber, randomWord;
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * verbArray.length);
    randomWord = verbArray[randomNumber];
    return randomWord;

  };
})();


// Function to generate and display to console Word 3 - Random Plural Noun

var word3 = (function() {
  var nounArray = [];
  nounArray.push("House");
  nounArray.push("Cat");
  nounArray.push("Dog");
  nounArray.push("Phone");
  nounArray.push("Computer");
  nounArray.push("Bottle");
  return function() {
    var randomWord, randomNumber;
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * nounArray.length);
    randomWord = nounArray[randomNumber];
    return randomWord;
  };
})();


// Function to generate and display to console Word 4 - Random Verb
var word4 = (function() {
  var verbArray = [];
  verbArray.push("Running");
  verbArray.push("Jumping");
  verbArray.push("Walking");
  verbArray.push("Sleeping");
  verbArray.push("Jogging");
  verbArray.push("Typing");
  return function() {
    var randomNumber, randomWord;
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * verbArray.length);
    randomWord = verbArray[randomNumber];
    return randomWord;
  };
})();



//Function to create password as one-line string
function passwordfinal() {
  let passwordfinal = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    passwordfinal += word1() + " " + word2() + " " + word3() + " " + word4() + " " + "\n";
  }
  return passwordfinal
};

console.log(passwordfinal());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, if its not too much to ask, can you explain how that works as i dont understand how, and the Code Geek video i watched didnt help.

Cheers

Comment: @Sam this is what's called a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). The `for` takes three arguments, an initial `int` (number) assigned to a variable (`i`), in this case `0`. Then the next argument is, "as long as `i` is less than three, loop again", the third is an increment, basically, every time the `for` runs, add `1` to the value of `i`. So, this `for` will run 3 times, until `i` = `3`, and since 3 is not less than 3, the loop stops.

Comment: Inside the `for` loop, this particular code is concatenating a password to the `passwordfinal` variable on every loop. Once the loop is done, it will return the value of the `passwordfinal` variable - which now contains three passwords.

Comment: @disinfor Ok great thank you for explaining, i'll play around with it some more to further my understanding, how would i get this for loop to display on 3 different lines in the console? ive had a go with 'process.stdout.write(i + " ");' but i got a weirder output:
 0 1 2 4 Ecastatic House Running 6 Angry Computer Running 5 Cheerful Dog Sleeping

Comment: @disinfor please disregard my second request for help i typed the code in and made a typo, thank you again for explaining for loops to me it is greatly appreciated

Comment: @Sam if you look in the snippet I added to the answer, you can see I added `+ "\n"` to the end of the `passwordfinal` concatenate variable. That is the "new line" code.